# SELECT returning X times the same results

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return the same results of a SELECT request, but with only 1 field change (email).

```
SELECT `field1`, 'myemail_1@gmail.com' as email, `nom`, `prenom`
FROM my_table
WHERE field1 = 1
AND field2 = 2
LIMIT 200
```

Return

```
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Valjean,Jean
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Tran,Jerome
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Doe,John
```

I need:

```
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Valjean,Jean
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Tran,Jerome
1,myemail_1@gmail.com,Doe,John
1,myemail_2@gmail.com,Valjean,Jean
1,myemail_2@gmail.com,Tran,Jerome
1,myemail_2@gmail.com,Doe,John
```

In a single request.
Thanks for help

Comment: You should try with [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) operator.

Comment: Do you have an exemple with my request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UNION (which will remove duplicates in your case there aren't any duplicates )

```
SELECT `field1`, 'myemail_1@gmail.com' as email, `nom`, `prenom`
FROM my_table
WHERE field1 = 1
AND field2 = 2
LIMIT 200
UNION 
SELECT `field1`, 'myemail_2@gmail.com' as email, `nom`, `prenom`
FROM my_table
WHERE field1 = 1
AND field2 = 2
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Nice simple solution, thanks